# C#: Using ContainsKey where the keys are objects

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary, hashcode, containskey

Ok so I need a bit of help. I have a generic dictionary "cashdata". The keys of this dictionary are objects (Query objects, a class I have defined). Query objects have "Terms" field, which is a list of strings, and an "Operator" field, which is an enum (Either "All" or "Any").

```
cashdata.ContainsKey(a_query_object);
```

And have it yield true or false depending on if a_query_object and an object in the dictionary are identical in terms of their Terms and Operator. What is the best way to do this? A HashCode possibly? I would appreciate an example, thanks in advance.

EDIT: cashdata Dictionary is defined as such

```
Dictionary<Query,List<string> > cashData = new Dictionary<Query,List<string>>();
```

Comment: please show more code and or how you have defined this Generic Dictionary please.

Comment: Override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on your custom object, put breakpoints in, and step through the code -- this will help you understand how `ContainsKey`, as well as other methods of the dictionary, works.

Comment: Be sure that the Terms and Operator of Query objects cannot change after they've been added to the Dictionary. If that does happen, you will not be able to find the object properly in the Dictionary.

Comment: If you can't override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on your custom object, provide an [IEqualityComparer<Query>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) to the dictionary constructor. The MSDN topic has a good example.

Answer (score 1):

Make your object implement [IEquatable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) along with overriding `Object.Equals` and `GetHashCode` as mentioned in the remarks section in MSDN

> If you implement IEquatable, you should also override the base
>   class implementations of Object.Equals(Object) and GetHashCode so that
>   their behavior is consistent with that of the IEquatable.Equals
>   method. If you do override Object.Equals(Object), your overridden
>   implementation is also called in calls to the static
>   Equals(System.Object, System.Object) method on your class. In
>   addition, you should overload the op_Equality and op_Inequality
>   operators. This ensures that all tests for equality return consistent
>   results.

Comment: Be careful with `IEquatable`. [Inheritance and IEquatable do not mix](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/01/05/inheritance-and-iequatable-do-not-mix/)

Comment: @JimMischel i am not sure what i made that was different than your code, but i tried the first test with the same code you have(simple copy & paste) and i had false returned 4 times, in both cases (with and without the symbols)